# Sorting Sql Table by combining multiple column as a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me. I have a problem in sorting result. I have a `product` table name with the columns

```
ProductID, name, price,...
```

and the `Promotion` table with columns

```
PromoID, startDate, EndDate, SalePrice, ProductID,.....
```

I want to retrieve the products by price.

I want to sort the price by asc and desc. I want to sort the price column in `Product` table and `SalePrice` column in `Promotion` table as a one column because I want to show promotion price to users if the product is on promotion.

Please how can I solve that problem? Is it possible to combine multiple columns as one in sorting?

Comment: God, you want everything. What is it that you don't want? :P.. hehehe..jst kidding. but atleast show what have you done so far

Comment: You mean like ORDER BY price DESC, SalePrice?

Comment: Show us some **sample data** for your `Products` and `Promotions` table, and show us the desired output

Comment: Are you saying, you want to show the promotional price, if one exists? How else should "as a [single] column" be read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you seem to want a single price column try along

```
SELECT
    Prod.productID,
    ISNULL(Prom.salePrice, Prod.price)
FROM Product Prod
JOIN Promotion Prom
  ON Prod.productID = Prom.productID
  AND Prom.startDate <= CONVERT (date, GETDATE())
  AND Prom.endDate >= CONVERT (date, GETDATE());
```

Comment: The question is tagged SQL Server - so you should use ISNULL instead of IFNULL.

Comment: Sure. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Thank you so much .It is working perfectly with ISNULL .

Answer (score 0):

Use the query

```
select (what you want) 
from product 
inner join promotion on product.productid = promotion.promoid 
order by price, salesprice asc
```

(what you want) should not be ambiguous, i.e. use like `product.productprice`, `promo.promoprice` etc.